# How do you make `pub run angular_test` kill pub serve when it finishes

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I want to run dart unit tests on a Windows Jenkins server.  The problem is when the tests complete, it prints

```
`pub serve` was not terminated
```

and waits for user input before (Ctrl-C x2) returning to the console.  This causes Jenkins to not know the tests completed, causing an eventual timeout build failure.  Is there a way to make pub run test/angular_test return to the console when the tests are completed?

Comment: In the latest versions of AngularDart, we are no longer using `pub serve` because of problems like this and old architecture. What version of AngularDart are you using?

Comment: @matanlurey So could you please tell what setup you are using? `pub serve` is convenient, but this is very annoying. I am using `4.0.0`

Comment: My setup:

environment:
  sdk: '>=1.24.2 <2.0.0'
dependencies:
  angular: ^4.0.0+2

Comment: I've found if I run pub serve in a separate console, I can get `pub run test` test to return to the prompt when it finishes by using the --pub-serve option to point it to the port being served in the other console.  However, it doesn't look like you can run angular_test without it starting its own instance of pub serve.

Comment: @matanlurey what do you use then?  pub run angular_test automatically launches pub serve.  Are you saying not to use angular_test?